# Cannot set a Loader while big component renders

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to show a loader while my Analysis component (and its children) load but I cannot for the life of me get this to work.

The main idea is:

```
<Context>
  <Admin>
    <Analysis (with other child components) />
  </Admin>
</Context>
```

The Admin component has a sidebar and the main view that is based upon a Switch/Router as seen here:

```
 const Admin = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { pageLoading } = useContext();

  return (
    <>
      <Box display="flex">
        <Sidebar
          routes={sidebarRoutes}
          logo={{
            innerLink: "/",
            imgAlt: "...",
          }}
        />
        <Box position="relative" flex="1" className={classes.mainContent}>
          <Switch>
            { pageLoading ? 
            <Loader />
            : (<Route
            path="/admin/stats"
            component={Analysis}
            key={"stats"} />) }
          </Switch>
          <Container
            maxWidth={false}
            component={Box}
            classes={{ root: classes.containerRoot }}
          >
          </Container>
        </Box>
      </Box> 
    </>
  );
};
```

However, since the Analysis component and its children take a while to load, I want to display a loader like this (no API calls are made):

[My current loading screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrvIq.png)

See, the problem is that I tried setting the context loading state in my useEffect hook inside the Sidebar component, like this:

```
  const handleTabClick = () => {
    setPageLoading(true);
  };
```

And then stopping the loader using the same context after the Analysis component mounts:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setPageLoading(false);
  }, []);
```

...And the loader gets stuck forever...
My conclusion is that when the Context component has its state changed and re-renders, the Admin component then has pageLoading field set to "true" and doesn't display the Analysis component.

What can I do to fix this? It's not crucial for my website but I'm trying to find a solution to this clunkiness. Clicking on the "Analysis" tab changes URLs in my browser search bar above, but nothing happens for a few seconds while the Analysis component loads. Looks stupid.

Comment: One side-issue you're going to run into is that `Loader` cannot be a direct descendent of `Switch`. Only `Route` or `Redirect` are allowed, anything else will break it (and the functionality of a `Switch` means it doesn't make sense to pass anything which doesn't accept router props anyway). It seems like you've already identified your core problem - if `Analysis` is "loading", it can't mount and set itself to "loaded". The logic which is render-blocking needs to happen at a higher level in the component tree than the conditionally rendered components.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this with following ugly solution:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Loader from "./Loader";

function SubPageLoader({path, component, key}) {
  const [updates, setUpdates] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    // stupid solution to postpone loading of children, so we can show a loading screen. TODO: find a better method
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setUpdates(updates => updates + 1);
    }, 1);
    if (updates > 1) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [updates]);

  return (
    <>
    {updates == 0 ? <Loader /> 
      : <Route
          path={path}
          component={component}
          key={key}
        /> }
  </>
  );
}
export default SubPageLoader;
```

This basically postpones the children load by 1 millisecond and that way we can instantly enter the new tab and show a loader without having to update parent states.